# How to filter out string with single quotes using Query DSL in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, querydsl

I have to filter out a string with single quotes like `'lang': 'en'` using Query DSL.

I used the following query:

```
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "message",
          "query": "*\'lang'\: \'en\'*"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
}
```

But it's not working.

I also tried using double slash (`\\`) character to escape the single quote (`'`), but it's sill not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to escaping `colon`.
Below query will give you expected result:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\\'lang\\'\\: \\'en\\'",
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}
```

Also, dont give `*` in starting and ending of query.

Comment: its only filtering out lang and not the entire string. the quotes for lang are also not being filtered out

Comment: as you are using query_string type of query and it has default operator as `OR` so set `"default_operator": "AND"` . please check update answer.

Comment: Still not working even after adding "default_operator": "AND"

Comment: can you please put some simple document value. so it will easy to give solution.

Comment: Can u please explain "simple document value"

Comment: I means post some of the documents value as sample data in question so it will be helpful in answering.